Error while running npx react-native start
ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config timed out

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'D:\INature_EForestrails_App\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config timed out

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 7m 58s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config timed out FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Settings file 'D:\INature_EForestrails_App\android\settings.gradle' line: 3 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'. > ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config timed out * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 7m 58s.

i was just trying to run that command but this error. my gradle version is 8.8. is there any issue with emulator?

Try the answers on this link https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/2490#issuecomment-2346848565.

no bro its not working,

Seems like a problem with internal libraries not getting linked properly, can you share your settings.gradle file?
